# Is there a *clean* way to make a read-only dependency-property reflect the value of another property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

The code below is my current solution.

**A great example of what I am trying to mimic would be the FrameworkElement.ActualWidth property.** You know how the ActualWidth property is calculated and reassigned, whenever the Width property changes, or whenever the control is redrawn, or whenever else? ------

From the developer's perspective, it just looks like data-binding hard-at-work.
But ActualWidth is a read-only dependency-property. Does Microsoft really have to go through this gigantic trash-hole of code to make that work? Or is there a simpler way that utilizes the existing functionality of the data-binding system?

```
public class foo : FrameworkElement
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(int))]
    public class fooConverter : IValueConverter
    {   public object Convert(  object value, Type targetType,
                                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        { ... }
        public object ConvertBack(  object value, Type targetType,
                                    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        { ... }
    }

    private static readonly fooConverter fooConv = new fooConverter();



    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ReadOnlyIntPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly( "ReadOnlyInt", typeof(int),
                                             typeof(foo), null);
    public int ReadOnlyInt
    {   get { return (int)GetValue(ReadOnlyIntPropertyKey.DependencyProperty); }
    }



    public static readonly DependencyProperty ReadWriteStrProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "ReadWriteStr", typeof(string), typeof(foo),
                                     new PropertyMetadata(ReadWriteStr_Changed));
    public string ReadWriteStr
    {   get { return (string)GetValue(ReadWriteStrProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ReadWriteStrProperty, value); }
    }



    private static void ReadWriteStr_Changed(   DependencyObject d,
                                            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {   try
        {   if (d is foo)
            {   foo f = d as foo;
                f.SetValue( ReadOnlyIntPropertyKey,
                            fooConv.Convert(f.ReadWriteStr, typeof(int), null,
                                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll need most of what you have.  The IValueConverter isn't required in this case, so you could simplify it down to just:

```
public class foo : FrameworkElement
{
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ReadOnlyIntPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly( "ReadOnlyInt", typeof(int),
                                         typeof(foo), null);
    public int ReadOnlyInt
    {
       get { return (int)GetValue(ReadOnlyIntPropertyKey.DependencyProperty); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ReadWriteStrProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "ReadWriteStr", typeof(string), typeof(foo),
                                 new PropertyMetadata(ReadWriteStr_Changed));

    public string ReadWriteStr
    {
       get { return (string)GetValue(ReadWriteStrProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ReadWriteStrProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void ReadWriteStr_Changed(DependencyObject d,
                                        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         foo f = d as foo;
         if (f != null)
         {
              int iVal;
              if (int.TryParse(f.ReadWriteStr, out iVal))
                  f.SetValue( ReadOnlyIntPropertyKey, iVal);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm used to seeing converters, because they are all over the place in the bindings in my app. I put it in with the small hope that a binding could be used here in the place of a PropertyChangedCallback. I guess this is just how it is ...

Comment: The one thing to remember - one callback can handle ALL of your read only properties, though.  You don't need to have one per property, so it's really not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as bad as you suggest, IMHO...

You could get rid of the converter : `IValueConverter` is for bindings, you don't need it for conversions in code-behind. Apart from that, I don't see how you could make it more concise...

Comment: Ha, fair enough. The code has to be managable at some point, right? But wouldn't this be so much nicer if we COULD just use a binding with some special parameters, and snap the converter in to do all the work? I don't have terribly high hopes, but I'm asking this question on SO simply to confirm that this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Oh! In response to your first statement, I should say that I am a hardcore C++ man. .NET (even C#) has always made me queasy, because it's so restrictive in comparison. I like to have percise control over the ways everything is executed. Alas, this may be somewhat hazardous to my .NET development...

Comment: @Giffguy I have the opposite experience. For hard core lock-free concurrency code, I had to give up on C++ because I was spending too much time trying to stop the compiler from ruining correctness by trying to outsmart me with micro-optimizations. C++ traditionally seems to wear 'not guaranteeing a memory model' as a badge of honor, but in hindsight, it's a quaint embarrassment at best or wanton abdication at worst. Only once I could rely on the set-in-stone memory access guarantees on .NET was my lock-free concurrent NLP parser able to soar, and quite favorably vs. native might I add.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a clean way to "make a **read-only** `DependencyProperty` reflect the value of another property," but it may require a pretty fundamental shift in the overall property programming model of your app. In short, instead of using the `DependencyPropertyKey` to ***push*** values into the property, every read-only `DependencyProperty` can have a **CoerceValue** callback which builds its own value by ***pulling*** all the source values it depends on.

In this approach, the 'value' parameter that's passed in to `CoerceValue` is ignored. Instead, each DP's `CoerceValue` function recalculates its value "from scratch" by directly fetching whatever values it needs from the `DependencyObject` instance passed in to `CoerceValue` (you can use `dobj.GetValue(...)` for this if you want to avoid casting to the owner instance type).

Try to suppress any suspicion that ignoring the value supplied to `CoerceValue` may be wasting something. If you adhere to this model, those values will never be useful and the overall work is the same or less than a "push" model because source values that haven't changed are, as always, cached by the DP system. All that's changed is who's responsible for the calculation and where it's done. What's nice here is that calculation of each DP value is always centralized in one place and specifically associated with that DP, rather than strewn across the app.

You can throw away the `DependencyPropertyKey` in this model because you'll never need it. Instead, to update the value of any read-only DP you just call `CoerceValue` or `InvalidateValue` on the owner instance, indicating the desired DP. This works because those two functions don't require the DP ***key***, they use the public `DependencyProperty` identifier instead, and they're public functions, so any code can call them from anywhere.

As for when and where to put these `CoerceValue`/`InvalidateValue` calls, there are two options:

- ***Eager:***   Put an `InvalidateValue` call for the (target) DP in the `PropertyChangedCallback` of every (source) DP that's ***mentioned*** in the (target) DP's `CoerceValueCallback` function,
     *--or--*
- ***Lazy:***   Always call `CoerceValue` on the DP immediately prior to fetching its value.

It's true that this method is not so XAML-friendly, but that wasn't a requirement of the OPs question. Considering, however, that in this approach you don't ever even need to fetch or retain the `DependencyPropertyKey` at all, it seems like it might one of the sleekest ways to go, if you're able to reconceive your app around the "pull" semantics.

---

In a completely separate vein, there's yet another solution that may be even simpler:

Expose `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `DependencyObject` and use CLR properties for the read-only properties, which will now have a simple backing field. Yes, the **WPF** binding system will correctly detect and monitor both mechanisms--`DependencyProperty` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`--on the same class instance. A setter, private or otherwise, is recommended for pushing changes to this read-only property, and this setter should check the backing field to detect vacuous (redundant) changes, otherwise raising the old-style CLR `PropertyChanged` event.

For binding to this read-only property, either use the owner's `OnPropertyChanged` overload (for self-binding) to push in the changes from DPs, or, for binding from arbitrary external properties, use `System.ComponentModel.DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty` to get a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` for the relevant souce DPs, and use its `AddValueChanged` method to set a handler which pushes in new values.

Of course for non-DP properties or non-`DependencyObject` instances, you can just subscribe to their `INotifyPropertyChanged` event to monitor changes that might affect your read-only property. In any case, no matter which way you push changes into the read-only property, the event raised by its setter ensures that changes to the read-only property correctly propagate onwards to any further dependent properties, whether WPF/DP, CLR, data-bound or otherwise.